# Moving locked partitions

Tags: 14.04, partitioning

I have Windows and Ubuntu systems on my laptop. I need to expand Linux partition. Since I can expand partitions to the bottom space I need to move `sda3` to unallocated space and then expand Linux partitions in freed space. I have booted from live USB and found that I can only copy `ext4` partition `sda3` and `sda6` copy menu is inactive. I see key picture near both of these partitions probably that is why I can't copy them? What is this key means and how to solve my problem with expanding partition?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot from live media.
Right click the unallocated space and delete it. It will become free space, then move your extended partition `/dev/sda3` to the free space. Now there will be free space available after extended partition.Also delete the `swap` partition. Now extend your primary partition `/dev/sda5` to as much space as you wish. Then create a new `swap` partition of 2 GB after `/dev/sda5`.

Comment: Why do I need to delete swap partition? Is it safe? My bootloader will be happy after such operations?

Comment: You may move` swap` alternatively to free space at the end of extended partition if it allows, otherwise delete it and extend `/dev/sda5` then create `swap` again. Deleting swap will not affect your system if you have a good amount of RAM (2GB or more)

Answer (score 2):

The key appears because the swap partition is mounted when using the live USB.  It appears on two partitions because swap is a 'subpartition' of an extended partition.

You can turn swap off with `sudo swapoff -a` and this will unlock the partitions.

Comment: Or right click on the partition in gparted and choose "unmount".